# Oracle bulk copy importing wrong data

Tags: oracle11g, datatable, connection, bulkinsert, bulk

I am trying to import data from an excel sheet to an Oracle table. I am able to extract the correct data, but when I run the following code:

$bulkCopy = new-object ("Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleBulkCopy") $oraClientConnString

```
        $bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = $entity
        $bulkCopy.BatchSize = 5000
        $bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 10000

        $bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dt)

        $bulkcopy.close()
        $bulkcopy.Dispose()
```

The data inserted in the table is some garbage values, consisting of 0's and 10's.

Value received from excel is stored in a data table ($dt).

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please check the data type of the values in your data table. i have experienced this issue in .Net with the data type Double. when i change my data type to Decimal, everything was fine.